# opencv FisherFaceRecognizer's train() function shows TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy, dlib

I'm trying to modify the [following code](http://www.paulvangent.com/2016/06/30/making-an-emotion-aware-music-player/)  by training OpenCV's Fisher Face classifier for particular images of faces. And I don't know why the code below shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_model.py", line 109, in <module>
    update(emotions)
  File "create_model.py", line 104, in update
    run_recognizer(emotions)
  File "create_model.py", line 101, in run_recognizer
    fishface.train(np.array(training_data), npar_trainlabs)
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

`training_data` contains dlib's vectorized_landmarks and I'm converting them to numpy array, and `training_labels` is just either label 1 or 2.

Functions involved in `Traceback` are following ones:

```
fishface = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
emotions = ["True", "Glasses"]

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

def get_landmarks(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    cimage = clahe.apply(gray)
    detections = detector(cimage, 1)
    landmarks_vectorised = []
    for k, d in enumerate(detections):  # For all detected face instances individually

        shape = predictor(cimage, d)  # Draw Facial Landmarks with the predictor class
        xlist = []
        ylist = []
        for i in range(1, 68):  # Store X and Y coordinates in two lists
            xlist.append(float(shape.part(i).x))
            ylist.append(float(shape.part(i).y))

        xmean = np.mean(xlist)  # Get the mean of both axes to determine centre of gravity
        ymean = np.mean(ylist)
        xcentral = [(x - xmean) for x in xlist]  # get distance between each point and the central point in both axes
        ycentral = [(y - ymean) for y in ylist]

        if xlist[26] == xlist[
            29]:  # If x-coordinates of the set are the same, the angle is 0, catch to prevent 'divide by 0' error in function
            anglenose = 0
        else:
            anglenose = int(math.atan((ylist[26] - ylist[29]) / (xlist[26] - xlist[29])) * 180 / math.pi)

        if anglenose < 0:
            anglenose += 90
        else:
            anglenose -= 90

        landmarks_vectorised = []

        if len(detections) < 1:
            landmarks_vectorised = "error"

        for x, y, w, z in zip(xcentral, ycentral, xlist, ylist):
            landmarks_vectorised.append(x)
            landmarks_vectorised.append(y)
            meannp = np.asarray((ymean, xmean))
            coornp = np.asarray((z, w))
            dist = np.linalg.norm(coornp - meannp)
            anglerelative = (math.atan((z - ymean) / (w - xmean)) * 180 / math.pi) - anglenose
            landmarks_vectorised.append(dist)
            landmarks_vectorised.append(anglerelative)
    return landmarks_vectorised


def make_sets(labels):
    training_data = []
    training_labels = []
    for label in labels:
        training = glob.glob("data\\%s\\*" % label)
        print(len(training))

        for item in training:
            try:
                image = cv2.imread(item)
            except:
                continue
            print(item)

            landmarks_vectorised = get_landmarks(image)

            if landmarks_vectorised == "error":
                print("error with landmarks")
                pass
            else:
                training_data.append(landmarks_vectorised)
                if str(label) == "True":
                    training_labels.append(2)
                elif str(label) == "Glasses":
                    training_labels.append(1)

    print("sets created")
    return training_data, training_labels

def make_sets(labels):
    training_data = []
    training_labels = []
    for label in labels:
        training = glob.glob("data\\%s\\*" % label)
        print(len(training))

        for item in training:
            try:
                image = cv2.imread(item)
            except:
                continue
            print(item)

            landmarks_vectorised = get_landmarks(image)

            if landmarks_vectorised == "error":
                print("error with landmarks")
                pass
            else:
                training_data.append(landmarks_vectorised)
                if str(label) == "True":
                    training_labels.append(2)
                elif str(label) == "Glasses":
                    training_labels.append(1)

    print("sets created")
    return training_data, training_labels


def run_recognizer(emotions):
    training_data, training_labels = make_sets(emotions)
    print("training fisher face classifier")
    print(type(training_data))
    print(type(training_labels))

    npar_train = np.array(training_data)
    npar_trainlabs = np.array(training_labels)
    fishface.train(np.array(training_data), npar_trainlabs)

def update(emotions):
    run_recognizer(emotions)
    fishface.save("glasses.xml")

update(emotions)
```

Please help me understand the meaning of such an error.

Comment: Hi! You need to add more information / context to this question.  First of all - we need to know which line is throwing the TypeError - you need to copy the whole Backtrace that you get when the error is thrown.  You should also show how `training_data` and `training_labels` are defined.  It's quite likely one of the first two lines of the block of 3 that is failing, not the call to `fishface.train()`.

Comment: @JRichardSnape thank you for your response! I have made the necessary changes. Could please give me some feedback regarding those?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your `training_data` and its `dtype`, maybe you can put them in a `list`, then transform the list to `np.array`. Do the same operations to your labels.

Comment: Hi - this is a comment rather than an answer.  It's good debugging advice but doesn't answer the question (mainly because you can't as yet).  I tend to agree it is probably either `training_data` or the labels that are not array type.

Comment: @Richard, Thank you for your remind. I agree with you, the `training_data` may be the problem.

Comment: @JRichardSnape, Chenqi, thank you, but as you can see from the modified post above, they are both type of list.

Comment: Hi, mjackie. Could you show me the details of `get_landmarks(image)` in the function `make_sets()`? I need to know the type of items in `training_data`, not the type of `training_data`.

Comment: @Chenqi Sorry, misunderstood you! I have added those functions.

Comment: According to your `get_landmarks()` function, there are some confusions in your code. First, you declared `landmarks_vectorised` twice(one in front of the first `for` loop, the second one will clear the previous values in the next loop), which means that the returned `landmarks_vectorised` contains only one facial landmark at last.  Second, the opencv document[link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html) shows that the src should be vector<mat> in C++. So the `training_data` should has a shape of `n*w*h`. You should transform your data with shape of `n*1*L`.

Comment: Sorry for the comments can only contain 600 characters. In the last comment, `L`  is the length of `landmarks_vectorised`. In the original code, your `training_data` has a shape of `n*L`. Add `npar_train = np.expand_dims(npar_train, axis=1)`  behind `npar_train = np.array(training_data)` will resolve this problem. Good luck!